# JPA transaction stores insertions inmediatly in DataBase

Tags: java, transactions, jta

When I save a new entity inside the transactional (TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) method `createEntities` the entities are stored inmediatly in the DB before the transaction is finished. I expected that the transaction was finished and the changes propagated to DB when the createEntities method finished but if I debug and pause the execution in the syso lines I can see the changes in DB in an external app (Toad for example).

Am I wrong in my guessing or am I configuring methods wrong?

My code is like this below:

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private MyService myService;
    
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void aMethod() {
        // don't want a transaction because this method does a lot of calculations
        // and lasts a lot of time resulting in transaction timeout otherway
        
        createEntities();
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void createEntities() {
        myService.createEntity(new MyEntity(1, "111"));
        System.out.println("Paused execution, checked DB and saw the entity was already inserted");
        myService.createEntity(new MyEntity(2, "222"));
        System.out.println("Paused execution, checked DB and saw the entity was already inserted");
    }
}

@Stateless
public class MyService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    public void createEntity(MyEntity entity) {
        em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@TransactionAttribute` works only if the Method is called from another Bean.
If you call `aMethod()` from some other Bean, the call will be intercepted to suspend an eventually active Transcation.
Then `createEntities()` is then called with no Transaction active, but this call will not be intercepted, because it is called from inside the MyClass-Bean.
Therefore no Transaction will be started.
The `createEntity()`-Method is not annotated and therefore has `TransactionAttribute.Required` active.
And because this Method isn't called from the same Bean and no Transaction is active, the Container will start a new one. This Transaction gets commited at the end of the Method.

More about Container-Manged Transcations: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html